# Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, дефис-тире

> Че сказать, красиво.

Ставится ли вообще запятая? Или нужно тире?

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

***Че сказать, красиво.***

Другими словами (в нейтральном стиле): ***Что и говорить, красиво.***

**Что и говорить** — вводное выражение со значением: Разг. Неизм. Вне всякого сомнения, совершенно определенно; действительно.

Обособляется запятой.

[https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=что+и+говорить&from=xx&to=ru&did=phraseology&stype=](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B8+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&from=xx&to=ru&did=phraseology&stype=)